# Socket with Python Server and c# client

Tags: c#, python, sockets, server, client

I'm working on a server/client architecture for socket communication using a python server and C# client! this application is used for transfering a file through socket. The problem that I'm getting is that the server written in python never get out from the ( while data!="" ) loop and after receiving the whole file it get blocked on the instruction ( data = client.recv(128) )

here is my client code:

```
        try
        {
            using (StreamReader fs = new StreamReader(path,System.Text.Encoding.ASCII,false,128))
            {    
                while (str !="")
                {
                    Byte[] sentBytes= new Byte[data];
                    str = fs.ReadToEnd();
                    sentBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str);
                    clientSocket.Send(sentBytes);                             
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {             
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());              
        }
```

and this is the server code:

```
import socket
import timeit

port=15555
host = "127.0.0.1"
socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socket.bind((host,port))

socket.listen(5)
print ("waiting for connection..")

while True:
    client, addr = socket.accept()
    print ("Connection established to {}".format(addr)) 
    with open('received_file.csv','wb') as f:
        print ("file opened")
        size=0
        start=timeit.default_timer()
        data = client.recv(128)
        while data!="":         
            print ('receiving data= ',(size))
            f.write(data)
            size=size+128
            data = client.recv(128)
        stop=timeit.default_timer()
    f.close()
    time=stop-start
    print ("sending finished! time= ", time , " seconds")
    client.close()
socket.close()
```

help please!

Comment: how about sending a fileheader which says how much bytes it will send?

Comment: You ask client to receive 128 bytes and now you're complaining why it's waiting for these 128 bytes. Makes no sense...

Comment: As suggested above, you're going to need to communicate the file size or alternatively, send some terminator signal so that you know you've received the entire file.

Comment: `client.recv` will not return an empty buffer until the client side closes its socket. Also, if you are using python3, an empty `str` (`""`) will never equal an empty `bytes`: (`b""`). In python3, `recv` produces a `bytes` value. Probably better to use the implicit boolean conversion: `while data:`